# Way to count how many numbers of n digits whose sums of digits smaller or equal to a given number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know how to count the numbers of strings of n digits whose sums of digits smaller or equal to a given number. For example, if n = 2 and the given number is 7, then it would be 36. `(8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1)`

Because

```
00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
...
60, 61,
70
```

Are the numbers satisfied. But I don't know how to count for a general case with a given n and the sum of n digits.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: You used $00$ as an example of a two-digit number.  Do you mean a string with $n$ digits rather than a number with $n$ digits?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: If the digit sum is less than or equal to $9$, the problem can be reduced to a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem using a transformation.  However, if the digit sum is greater than $9$, we will have to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) or [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) to solve the problem since no summand can exceed $9$.

Comment: Do you have any hint on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many strings of decimal digits of length $n$ have digit sum at most $k$?

Let $x_i$ be the $i$th digit.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_n \leq k \tag{1}$$
is an inequality in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 9$ for each $i$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq n$.  If we let
$$s = k - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_n)$$ 
then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_n + s = k \tag{2}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions $x_i \leq 9$ for each $i$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq n$.  Observe that since the value of $s$ is determined by the values of $k$ and the $x_i$'s, equation 2 has the same number of solutions as inequality 1.

If $k \leq 9$, we do not need to consider the restrictions on the $x_i$'s.  A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of $n$ addition signs in a row of $k$ ones.

To illustrate, suppose we wish to find the number of four-digit decimal strings with digit sum at most $9$.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \leq 9 \tag{3}$$
and
$$s = 9 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)$$
so
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + s = 9 \tag{4}$$
Then
$$1 1 1 + + 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 2$, and $s = 3$ of equation 4 and the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$, and $x_4 = 2$ of inequality 3.

The number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways we can place $n$ addition signs in a row of $k$ ones, which is
$$\binom{k + n}{n}$$
since we must choose which $n$ of the $k + n$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Notice that for your example of two-digit strings with digit sum at most $7$, we obtain the inequality
$$x_1 + x_2 \leq 7$$
and the corresponding equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + s = 7$$
which has
$$\binom{7 + 2}{2} = \binom{9}{2} = 36$$
solutions, as you found.

If $k > 9$, then our formula includes solutions in which one or more summands could exceed $9$.  To handle this, we could use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to remove those cases.  If $k$ is sufficiently large, this could require a lot of work, making the use of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) more practical.